# Pass multiple values with button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, highlight

There are similar posts but I can't find a solution for my unique case.

I have a script which highlights a keyword when a user clicks the highlight button. Currently it is only highlighting the word "fox", but I need it to highlight additional words, in this case "fence" and "jumped".

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="inputText">
The fox quickly jumped over the fence.
</div>
<button onclick="highlight('fox')">Highlight</button>
```

I tried changing `'fox'` to `'+fox+','+fence+','+jumped+'` but no luck.

The javascript is:

```
function highlight(text)
{
    inputText = document.getElementById("inputText")
    var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML
    var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
    if ( index >= 0 )
    { 
        innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
        inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML 
    }

}
```

and CSS:

```
.highlight
{
background-color:yellow;}
```

Comment: Pass an `array` instead then loop through the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button onclick="highlight('fox')+highlight('jumped')+highlight('fence')">Highlight</button>
```

Comment: Everyone offered great solutions, but I wanted a simple change.. which is why I chose this one. Thanks everybody, really appreciate it.

Comment: A future tip while learning javascript is to look into best practices overall! Take a look at [Pragmatic Standards: JavaScript Coding Standards and Best Practices](https://github.com/stevekwan/best-practices/blob/master/javascript/best-practices.md)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `onclick` in your markup, you should try to utilize best practice and bind events through javascript only since it's the most unobtrusive way to attach handlers to DOM elements.

Furthermore you can define the words you want to highlight in an array that you iterate the highlighting code over, like the fiddle below.

```js
(function() {

  function highlight() {
    var wordsToHighlight = ["fox", "fence", "jumped"];

    wordsToHighlight.forEach(function(text) {
      inputText = document.getElementById("inputText")
      var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML
      var index = innerHTML.indexOf(text);
      if (index >= 0) {
        innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + text.length);
        inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML
      }
    });
  }

  button = document.getElementById('btn-highlight');
  button.onclick = highlight;
})();
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputText">The fox quickly jumped over the fence.</div>
<br/>
<button id="btn-highlight">Highlight</button>
```

Notice the `id="btn-highlight"` in the markup, and the binding of the `highlight` function to the click event.

Answer (score 1):

We can pass a delimited string and then split that into an array. You can use any delimiter you want, but I chose a comma. You can then loop through this array to highlight the words.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p927tsuu/)

```
<div id="inputText">
The fox quickly jumped over the fence.
</div>
<button onclick="highlight('fox,fence,jumped')">Highlight</button>

<script>

function highlight(text){

    var i, index, words = text.split(",");
    var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
    var innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML;

    for(i=0;i<words.length;i++){

      index = innerHTML.indexOf(words[i]);
      if (index >= 0) {
      innerHTML = innerHTML.substring(0,index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + innerHTML.substring(index,index+words[i].length) + "</span>" + innerHTML.substring(index + words[i].length);
    inputText.innerHTML = innerHTML;
      }

    }
}    

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better approach will be to use a pre-made dictionary like object:

DEMO and source : [**JSnippet DEMO**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/262/highlight-several-words-by-token-word-in-string)

JS:

```
var dic = {
   fox:['fox','jumped','fence'],
   cat:['cat','happy']
};
function parse(target) {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText");
    inputText.innerHTML = inputText.innerHTML.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
    if (typeof dic[target] === 'object')
        for (var i=0; i<dic[target].length; i++)
           tokenize(dic[target][i]);
}
function tokenize(text) {
    var inputText = document.getElementById("inputText"); 
    var inner = inputText.innerHTML;
    var index = inner.indexOf(text);
    if ( index >= 0 ) { 
        inner = inner.substring(0,index) + 
                "<span class='highlight'>" + inner.substring(index, index + text.length) + "</span>" + 
                inner.substring(index + text.length);
        inputText.innerHTML = inner;
    }
}
```